# How to use Google fonts in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, fonts, tailwind-css, font-family

I am making a website with Tailwind CSS and I want to use a custom font from Google fonts. I already imported the font in the HTML `<head>` tag and then I updated my `tailwind.config.js` file.

Unfortunately, when I add the utility class that references the imported font, the font doesn't change.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and how I should properly use Google fonts in Tailwind CSS.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@600&family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700;9..144,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sunnyside-agency-landing-page/tailwind.css" />

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Sunnyside agency landing page</title>
  </head>
  <body class="font-barlow">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        barlow: ['"Barlow"', "sans-serif"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

When I hover over the body class name, [this message pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGDc6.png).

[Here are the computed styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFJTz.png)

I also tried to remove the double quotes in `'"Barlow"'`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the content parameter on your `tailwind.config.js` to include your html files.

```js
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {
          fontFamily: {
            barlow: ['"Barlow"', "sans-serif"],
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
```